# We can't create an object in interface but how a return type can be a interface?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have start working on MVC. During some tutorial of [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in mvc I saw a property which return an [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) type as given below:-

```
    public IEnumerable<location> ListofLocation{get;set;}
```

The above property is a property of model which returns a list of locations which will populate in dropdown.

My question is "if we cannot create an object of interface, then why this return type in interface"?

Comment: Any reason why you feel you need to shout your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> but how a return type can be a interface?

By that it means the method can **return object of classes that implements that particular interface.**

For your example property.

```
public IEnumerable<location> ListofLocation{get;set;}
```

`ListofLocation` can be `List<Location>`  since [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) implements `IEnumrable<T>`

Comment: It means that this property can return arraylist,hastable,list or i can say any type of collection which inherits IEnumerable interface?

Comment: @user1648559, not inherit, implements should be the correct term, plus `ArrayList` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, also instead of ArrayList and HashTable you should look into their generic versions `List<T>` and Dictionary respectively (if you are using .Net framework 2.0 or higher)

Answer (score 1):

When you return an object that implements a particular interface, you get an object that only contains the public properties and methods that are defined on that interface.  All other methods that the object exposes *are masked off.*

That's what it means for an object to implement an interface.  That object *satisfies the interface's contract.*

Similarly, that same object may expose properties and methods that satisfy some other interface.  So you can also return an object of that other interface type, using the same object you used to satisfy the first interface.

Finally, an interface can be implemented by different objects.  This allows you to change out the underlying implementation (i.e. behavior) of the interface, while still fulfilling the interface's contract with the user of the interface.